# How to make new columns with reference to other data frame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    "BusId":['abc1','abc2','abc3'],
    "Fair Increase":[2,3,5]
})
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'BusId':['abc1','abc2','abc3','abc4','abc5'],
    "Fair":[5,6,7,8,9]
})
```

Need to compute only for **BusId** present in df1 on df2.

To calculate Increased Fair 
Fair in df2 + Fair Increase in df1

Expected Output:

```
BusId   Fair    Increased Fair
abc1    5           7
abc2    6           9
abc3    7           12
```

Comment: you need dataframe.join()

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,how='inner').assign(IncreasedFair=lambda x : x['Fair Increase']+x['Fair'])
`

Comment: no i need sum the values directly without join

Comment: yes, but adding them together involves a join operation before that. Don't be so hasty to say "no"

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @wen it works please put it as answer

Comment: @Yuca sure will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.merge` to merge df2 and df2, create a new column `Increased Fair` and delete the old column `Fair Increase`

```
>>> df3 = df2.merge(df1).set_index('BusId')
>>> df3['Increased Fair'] = df3['Fair'] + df3['Fair Increase']
>>> del df3['Fair Increase']
>>> df3
       Fair  Increased Fair
BusId                      
abc1      5               7
abc2      6               9
abc3      7              12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` with a dictionary lookup

```
m = dict(df2.values)
df1.assign(**{'Increased Fair': df1.BusId.map(m) + df1['Fair Increase']})

  BusId  Fair Increase  Increased Fair
0  abc1              2               7
1  abc2              3               9
2  abc3              5              12
```